# Haproxy redirecting

Tags: haproxy

I have a Haproxy to redirect from https://sede.example.com.br to https://sede.example.pub. The problem the Haproxy configuration is not following the redirection.

If I test with the curl command passing -L argument (follow redirects), it works fine

```
curl -L https://sede.example.com.br
```

But I need to work without the -L option, because and have an API system that make some Post and Get operation and doesn't follow redirection. So I need do that in the Haproxy.

The configuration:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
        option httplog
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg/certs/
        timeout http-request 60s
        timeout http-keep-alive 4s
        acl https ssl_fc
        http-request set-header         X-Forwarded-Proto http if !https
        http-request set-header         X-Forwarded-Proto https if https

        stats uri /haproxy?examplehaproxystats74581257445
        log-format %{+Q}o\ %{-Q}ci\ -\ -\ [%T]\ %r\ %ST\ %B\ \"\"\ \"\"\ %cp\ %ms\ %ft\ %b\ %s\ \%Tq\ $

        acl sede_acl req.hdr(host) -i -m str sede.example.com.br
        redirect code 301 prefix https://sede.example.pub if sede_acl
```

Any ideia in my configuration?

Comment: In general, haproxy healthchecks should be as fast and lightweight as possible. Doubling the number of requests is not compatible with that guideline (so it seems very reasonable to me for any ticket asking for this feature to be rejected). Why are you making it haproxy's job to do this, rather than either querying the correct backend in the first place, or having the server have an endpoint that indicates whether its dependencies are also up?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that. The reason that I have a lot of legacy code on the fields and need to improvise. Regards

Comment: It sounds as if you need a proxy, not a redirection.

Comment: yes, but i dont have the dest ip, only the dns.

Comment: then add domain name instead of IP in backend. `server foo name.example.com:443 ssl verify none`. domain name will be resolved at haproxy start. there are also options to define DNS resolvers in haproxy and update it in intervals - useful for cloud environments. given your issue you may also want to overwrite `Host` header. `http-request set-header Host 'sede.example.com'`. there may remain an issue of your backend creating links to its domain instead of your frontend. that's an application's issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try the following snipplet, it's untested but I hope you get the idea

```
frontend http-in
    option httplog
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg/certs/
    timeout http-request 60s
    timeout http-keep-alive 4s
    acl https ssl_fc
    http-request set-header         X-Forwarded-Proto http if !https
    http-request set-header         X-Forwarded-Proto https if https

    stats uri /haproxy?examplehaproxystats74581257445
    log-format %{+Q}o\ %{-Q}ci\ -\ -\ [%T]\ %r\ %ST\ %B\ \"\"\ \"\"\ %cp\ %ms\ %ft\ %b\ %s\ \%Tq\ $

    acl sede_acl req.hdr(host) -i -m str sede.example.com.br
    # redirect code 301 prefix https://sede.example.pub if sede_acl
    use_backend sede_acl if sede_acl
  
backend sede_acl
  http-request set-header Host sede.example.pub
  server sede-server sede.example.pub:443 sni sede.example.pub ssl
```